# Can we do with/without the definite article before an abstract noun?

Tags: definite-articles

Which is correct and why?

(a) He gave us a lecture on the importance of reading books.
(b) He gave us a lecture on importance of reading books.

IS the definite article required before the abstract noun here?

Comment: You need it. See many other questions on this site on definite article for explanations, or try ELL.

Answer (score 0):

**You need the definite article here.**

Abstract nouns don't need articles when they're expressing an abstract idea.

> Love is a many-splendored thing.

*Love* is an abstract noun and is being used in the abstract, so no article is needed.

However, when you're clarifying or specifying an abstract noun, you [need an article](https://www.lingq.com/en/learn-english-online/courses/91431/137-articles-with-abstract-nouns-1129908/).

> **The** love of money is the root of all evil.

Since you're specifying the love *of money* specifically, you use an article.

Comment: I disagree with your claim that *the love of money is the root of all evil* requires **the** at the start.